# Best way to pull data

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a SQL table that stores the date an email was created and then another table that gives details about that email (how long they spent writing the email, how long it was in a Draft mode etc).  The join between the two tables is through a key.

The problem is, it only stores the date the email was created (entered into the system) and data is only written to the table when the email is completed (sent).  So for yesterday, you may have 1000 emails completed that day, but their create date and time is varied.  Also the create date time column is only in one table.

My method right now is to join the two tables, and in the where clause I calculate the completed date by adding the number of seconds of the email write time to the created date time.

```
 WHERE DATEADD(s, ISNULL(a.emailwritetime,0), b.CreateDateTime) BETWEEN @start AND @end
```

(@start and @end are usually the previous day)

The tables have millions of rows, so expectedly, this takes a while to run and its hitting the production server to pull the data.  Can anyone suggest a better/cleaner way of pulling the data?  If you dont know what createdatetimes finished yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the value you're looking for.